# Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization Fortify Issue

Tags: java, jms, fortify

I am getting the Fortify issue:

```
Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization
```

on the below line:

```java
rapidMtoorderObj = (MyMessageObject)theMessage.getObject();
```

I have attached my JMS code snippet. 
Can anyone please check my JMS code and please explain why am I getting the issue and share the fix.

```java
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;

public class MyMessageBean extends MessageReceiver {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public MyMessageBean() { 
       super();
   }

   public void onMessage(Message message) {
      MyMessageObject rapidMtoorderObj = new MyMessageObject(); 

      try {  
         ObjectMessage theMessage = (ObjectMessage)message;
         rapidMtoorderObj = (MyMessageObject)theMessage.getObject(); 
         // Getting "Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization" in this line 

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ObjectMessage` objects depend on Java serialization to marshal and unmarshal their object payload. This process is generally considered unsafe, because a malicious payload can exploit the host system. [Lots of CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=objectmessage) have been created for this. For this reason, most JMS providers force users to explicitly whitelist packages that can be exchanged using `ObjectMessage` messages. For example, here's the related [documentation for ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#controlling-jms-objectmessage-deserialization).

There is no magic code fix for this issue that will eliminate the warning from Fortify aside from removing the use of `ObjectMessage` from your code altogether (which is what I would actually recommend).

There are a number of other issues with using JMS `ObjectMessage` not related to security that you should [read about](http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/).

Answer (score 0):

Another option (depending on your scenario), if you don't have access to the JMS provider or they don't provide this feature, is to use a (lookahead) ValidatingInputStream in your code so you can whitelist internally.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc/api/common/org/openjdk/jmc/common/io/ValidatingObjectInputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (ois.readObject() instanceof Object) {
          return (ois.readObject());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
```

**Use this if you have case where you use `readObject()`**